# How to load LUA modules in aquarium/scrapy-splash?

Tags: lua, scrapy-splash

I am working on a LUA script for scrapy-splash and want to use the `socket.http` module.
The module is installed, I have disabled the sandbox and configured the package path. But I can't get it to work.
My environment is aquarium on Linux.

I have installed `luasocket` using `luarocks` and added

`--disable-lua-sandbox --lua-package-path "/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/?.lua"`

to the splash instance in `docker-compose.yml`.

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
"error": {"info": {"type": "LUA_INIT_ERROR", "message": "[string \"<python>\"]:1: module 'socket.http' not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.http']
    no file '/app/splash/lua_modules/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/app/splash/lua_modules/libs/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/http/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/socket/http/init.lua'
    no file './socket/http.lua'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/socket/http.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/socket/http.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './socket/http.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.2/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.2/socket.so'
    no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/loadall.so'
    no file './socket.so'"}, "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script", "type": "ScriptError", "error": 400}, "qsize": 0, "status_code": 400}
```

Even though the file `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/http.lua` exists on my machine. I have also tried to `chmod 777` the file but it still throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was no need for me to use `socket.http`.

I am using [`splash:http_get`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html?highlight=http_get#splash-http-get) and [`splash:http_post`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html?highlight=http_get#splash-http-post) now and it is working fine.